# Scala: How to create a class method which return class variable value by taking variable name as string input

Tags: scala, class

I'm new to Scala, and I'm trying to write a class method in Scala which takes the class variable name (as string) as input and returns that variable value. Say I have a class `Person` with variables `name` and `age`. 
 I need a method `getVar` in class `Person` which can do

```
//Expected output in comments next to a method call

val p1 = new Person(name="abc",age=23);
p1.getVar("age"); //Returns 23
p1.getVar("name"); //Returns "abc"
```

I don't know how do I refer to that class variable by name in `getVar` method. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In a statically typed language, you normally do not want that. If you do want that, use a `Map`

Comment: Can you show us where you would need this? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @Thilo I'm trying to build a dynamic rule engine in Scala using Spark. So I need to apply these dynamic rules on Streaming Data. So only during run-time I'll get to know on which field I need to apply filter. As my incoming Streaming data is of type Dataset, I'm defining its schema using case class, in which I need this method to get the value of the field.

Comment: How would you know what type is supposed to be returned? If the compiler doesn't know the return type then you won't be able to operate on it. You can't add ints or compare strings if the compiler doesn't know if it's dealing with an `Int` or a `String`.

Comment: @jwvh forgot to specify that, this filter operation happens only on `Int` type fields, sorry for the wrong example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html).

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class FieldRequestSupport[SelfType <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag] {
    self: SelfType =>

    private val classFieldsAccessors: Map[String, MethodSymbol] = typeOf[SelfType].members.collect({
        case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
    }).flatMap(symbol => TermName.unapply(symbol.name).map((_, symbol)))(collection.breakOut)
    private val classMirror: Mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

    def requestField(fieldName: String): Option[Any] = {
        classFieldsAccessors.get(fieldName).map(
            symbol => classMirror.reflect(self).reflectField(symbol).get
        )
    }
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends FieldRequestSupport[Person]

object Test extends App {
    val person = Person("Bob", 26)
    println(person.requestField("name")) //will print Some(Bob)
    println(person.requestField("age")) //will print Some(26)
    println(person.requestField("qqq")) //will print None
}
```